# How to do something after multiple aysnc requests in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous

I have multiple async request running inside 2 loops. I want to reload the page when All the requests inside BOTH loops are done.

I'm a bit confused about this.

If I had one request I would just call window.location.reload in a then block.

If I had two requests I would make the other request in first then block and call window.location.reload inside the second request then block

How should I do this?

```
seImages.forEach((seImage) => {
  const se_image = {
    image: seImage.image,
    alt_text: seImage.alt_text,
    landing_page: newLp.id,
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken'),
  };

  const newSeImage = urlEncodedFormData(se_image);

  postFormData(
    ui.urls.createSeImage(),
    newSeImage
  ).then((resp) => console.log(resp));
});

vpPoints.forEach((vpPoint) => {
  const vp_point = {
    point: vpPoint.point,
    description: vpPoint.description,
    landing_page: newLp.id,
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken'),
  };

  const newVpPoint = urlEncodedFormData(vp_point);
  postFormData(
    ui.urls.createVpPoint(),
    newVpPoint
  ).then((resp) => console.log('VpPoint: ', resp));
});
```

Comment: Store the promises in an array and wait for `Promise.all`.

Comment: `Array.prototype.map()`+ `Promise.all()`

Comment: @ThomasSablik Do I have to add 2 Promise.all() inside the loops? can you give me an example. I'm using fetch to make requests.

Comment: You create an array like `const promises = [];` and push all the promises `promises.push(fetch(...));`. After all functions are started and all promises are stored you can simply wait for `await Promise.all(promises);`

Comment: @Andreas Why do we need map here?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Ok, let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an array like `const promises = [];` and push all the promises `promises.push(fetch(...));`. After all functions are started and all promises are stored you can simply wait for `await Promise.all(promises);`

```
const promises = [];

seImages.forEach((seImage) => {
  const se_image = {
    image: seImage.image,
    alt_text: seImage.alt_text,
    landing_page: newLp.id,
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken'),
  };

  const newSeImage = urlEncodedFormData(se_image);

  promises.push(postFormData(
    ui.urls.createSeImage(),
    newSeImage
  ).then((resp) => console.log(resp)));
});

vpPoints.forEach((vpPoint) => {
  const vp_point = {
    point: vpPoint.point,
    description: vpPoint.description,
    landing_page: newLp.id,
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken'),
  };

  const newVpPoint = urlEncodedFormData(vp_point);
  promises.push(postFormData(
    ui.urls.createVpPoint(),
    newVpPoint
  ).then((resp) => console.log('VpPoint: ', resp)));
});

(async function () {
    await Promise.all(promises);
    // window.location.reload
})();
```